# What file systems can work with OS X File Tags? (HFS+, ExFAT, NTFS, etc.)

Tags: windows, filesystem, ntfs, hfs+, finder-tag

What file systems can work with OS X File Tags? (HFS+, ExFAT, NTFS, etc.)

I have an NTFS data drive in a Windows machine that I might move to an external hard drive enclosure, if I can use Tags with the NTFS drive from my new Mac.  (it's a Seagate drive, so I'd use their free OS X NTFS driver)

If NTFS will not work with OS X File Tags, what other file systems will work with it?

Assuming that File Tags work with some file system that a Windows machine could read (including using third-party drivers), what would happen if I had tagged a file or directory, then disconnected the drive from my Mac, then attached it to my PC, then moved or modified the tagged file or directory, then disconnected the drive from my PC and connected it to my Mac?  Would the tag still be associated with the file?

Comment: So basically your goal is to find a file system which will allow you to share tags between OS X and Windows?

Comment: Wish you luck - I've been trying to find one for **years** Tags show over SMB on NTFS [remote drives], but I can't see them on the actual Win machine

Comment: I wasn't expecting tags to be usable from Windows, thought it would be nice if they were.  I just wanted to ensure that I could use tags on OS X on any file system, and from OS X without Windows messing them up.  I've done some more research.  It looks like tags are store in the .DS_Store folder, so any file system should work.  I imagine that if Windows changed a file's contents but not its path, then the tag would still be associated in OS X, but if the file's path were changed, then the tag would no longer be associated with the file.

Comment: Not enough info to be an answer, but Tags don't appear to work even on a local NTFS drive. They tag, you can see them, but Spotlight doesn't seem to index them, so they don't appear in tag searches [sidebar etc]

Comment: @XDR don't tags get saved as extended metadata attributes? They're essentially portable, so unless Windows does something really destructive (which is not out of the question btw) they should be preserved even if files are moved or edited outside of macOS.